# delete erroneous branch remotes/upstream/upstream/develop from git[hub]

Tags: git, github, branch

By accident, a branch `remotes/upstream/upstream/develop` has been created. Upstream is under GitHub control. The standard delete command fails:

```
$ git fetch --all
$ git branch -a
* develop
  master
  remotes/origin/HEAD -> origin/develop
  remotes/origin/develop
  remotes/origin/master
  remotes/upstream/develop
  remotes/upstream/master
  remotes/upstream/upstream/develop
$ git push upstream --delete upstream/develop
error: unable to delete 'upstream/develop': remote ref does not exist
error: failed to push some refs to 'git@github.com:...'
```

`.git/config` has the standard stanza

```
[remote "upstream"]
    url = git@github.com:...
    fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/upstream/*
```

Comment: Is it a copy-pasting error or did you purposefully (for some reason) forget to type 'git' at the start of your push command? (an alias maybe? If so just ignore my comment)

Comment: It was a stupid error; I corrected it in the question.

Comment: I tried to reproduce it, but for me `git` deleted the remote branch without any problems (besides a bit of human confusion on my side). Could you check and report the version of `git` you are using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently, the accidentally created branch was never pushed to the upstream server, or not accepted; anyway, `git branch fetch --all` did not propagate it to other clients. So it could be deleted locally with

```
$ git branch -r -D upstream/upstream/develop
Deleted remote-tracking branch upstream/upstream/develop (was e49bbca1).
```